# How to fix random crashes with Linux+AMD on Vulkan & Source Engine games?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, portal-2, linux, steam-play

## Problems:

- TF2 crash after 30 minutes of gameplay with random texture or dx8 errors
- Source games like Portal 2 (and mods like Thinking with Time Machine) or Insurgency does not start or crash
- Vulkan games does not start (Like Rise of tomb raider or talos principle)
- Steam play (Valve's winehq) cant start anything

### Applies to:

Linux (maybe all newer distros, I'm not sure), Ubuntu +16.XX (up to 18.04.1) with GPU AMD Radeon™ HD7700 or any newer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

1. Ignore stock (libre/open source) drivers
2. Ignore AMD website's Crimson or older driver recomendations
3. Check for latest AMD drivers (phoronix [1](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_topic&q=Radeon) is the best way)
4. download latest (for now August-2018) drivers [here: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-30](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-30)
5. check in the *AMD Radeon™ Product Family Compatibility* section if your GPU is compatible, **IF NOT: STOP.**

   - Note: some rebrands like r9 280x counts like a 7k series or else and it's listed :D
6. Download & Extract(all) your distro's driver and run the **PRO driver install NOT the basic installer**

   - Note: If you have already installed the basic or an old amdgpu driver installation first uninstall the old driver then install the new one (avoid to all cost to "update" the amdgpu driver)

`./amdgpu-pro-install`

7. Install (Valve's) [Vulkan SDK: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#linux](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#linux)

   - Note: the main goal is to add the variables to your `~/.profile`

`source /<your lunarG folder>/setup-env.sh`

Restart and test

### Reasons:

- Stock drivers lacks of privative/patented instructions
- AMD linux drivers webpages list are a really big mess
- AMD Stock drivers lacks of opencl, vulkan and other instructions
- Only pro drivers have the full stack of needed instructions
- Valve's vulkan api have extra vr and other nice instructions

#### SOURCES:

[1: Phoronix AMD news: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_topic&q=Radeon](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_topic&q=Radeon)